# Return Empty column if column does not exist in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created a dataframe `df` as below:

```
Type = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
Size = [72,23,66,12]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Type': Type, 'Size': Size})
```

I can extract any existing column using:

```
df_count = df['Size']
```

However, if a data frame is too big, and I don't know if the column exist in df or not. In such if I call a column e.g. `df['Shape']` as below:

```
df_null = df['Shape']
```

It raises a `KeyError`. However I want that `df_null` should get an empty column with name `"Shape"`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.get`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.get.html#pandas.DataFrame.get) in a pattern similar to:

```
In [3]: df.get('Size', pd.Series(index=df.index, name='Size'))
Out[3]:
0    72
1    23
2    66
3    12
Name: Size, dtype: int64

In [4]: df.get('Shape', pd.Series(index=df.index, name='Shape'))
Out[4]:
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
Name: Shape, dtype: float64
```

Or generalize by creating a function to abstract this:

```
In [5]: get_column = lambda df, col: df.get(col, pd.Series(index=df.index, name=col))

In [6]: get_column(df, 'Size')
Out[6]:
0    72
1    23
2    66
3    12
Name: Size, dtype: int64

In [7]: get_column(df, 'Shape')
Out[7]:
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
Name: Shape, dtype: float64
```

Another alternative could be to use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [`squeeze`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html):

```
In [8]: df.reindex(columns=['Size']).squeeze()
Out[8]:
0    72
1    23
2    66
3    12
Name: Size, dtype: int64

In [9]: df.reindex(columns=['Shape']).squeeze()
Out[9]:
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
Name: Shape, dtype: float64
```

Comment: @root Nice!  `get`  Awesome.  I have never seen that used until now.  I will add that to my toolbox.  +1

Comment: Would it be possible to fill the missing column with "1" instead of "NaN"?

Comment: @Eagle After the squeeze, please do this ``` df['Shape'] = df['Shape'].fillna(1) ```.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, try this

```
col = 'Shape'
df_null = pd.Series() if col not in df.columns else df[col]
```

Output:

```
Series([], dtype: float64)
```

OR

```
col = 'Size'
df_null = pd.Series() if col not in df.columns else df[col]
```

Output:

```
0    72
1    23
2    66
3    12
Name: Size, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Nice usage of condition here:-)

Comment: Sorry, a minor addition is required. The df_null should be of same no. of rows as df and fill all rows with 0 or NaN.